# Word-break:break-word not working in Firefox 21

Tags: css, firefox, word-break

I've added `word-break:break-word` to the comments on my site to start breaking up the words when they overflow the comment box, but it doesn't appear to be working in Firefox. I've done a JS fiddle of the setup and it does work. So something must be conflicting but I can't find it for the life of me.

JS Fiddle (working): http://jsfiddle.net/F6K99/6/

Live problem: http://bit.ly/13NcY5F

Comment: looks like there's a double semicolon there, maybe Firefox doesn't like it? http://d.pr/i/6IKo

Comment: Why do you want to bre ak words inste ad of proper word division?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can achieve this by the following:

**A.** Use `word-break:break-all;` instead of `word-break:break-word;`

[WORKING SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/F6K99/7/)

**B.** Or, Use `word-wrap: break-word;` instead of `word-break:break-word;`

[WORKING SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/F6K99/8/)

As far as I know, `word-break` does not have `break-word` attribute.

Hope this Helps.

Comment: Chrome supports "word-break: break-word;" which is different from "word-break:break-all;". It's more intelligent and will break inside of a word only if a break between words is not possible.

Comment: @Andrej - Can you produce a fiddle demonstrating what you have mentioned?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the following CSS.

```
word-break:normal;
word-wrap:normal;
```

This will work for both Chrome, Firefox.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is about breaking *within* words if they are longer than the container itself. Normal word wrapping/breaking merely breaks *between* words.

Comment: This solution worked for me, should be accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

u hv to use word-break:break-all;..it should work after that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143614/word-breakbreak-word-not-working-in-firefox-21/17143678#17143678